# Java JDBC connection error with JDK 9

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, java-9, mssql-jdbc

I created an entire JavaFX UI using the Java version 9, and I keep getting an error I dont understand when implementing the database code. If I change my version to Java 8, the database runs without any issues but my entire UI gets messed up.
I downloaded the latest jdbc driver and here's a basic connection code with the error message I get on Java 9:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
                "databaseName=SphereDB;integratedSecurity=true;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            // Establish the connection.
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
            }
        }

        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=54221:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Salman\IdeaProjects\DatabaseTest\out\production\DatabaseTest;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar" Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 14 more
```

PS. I'm using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: I think you actually have a problem where your UI seems to have some weird dependency on JDK version where it shouldn't. I would rarely expect a UI to get "messed up" when switching to lower JDK version - I would believe in "program will not compile", but not that.

Comment: Which version of the Microsoft JDBC driver are you using?